# A regex for an application version

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to write regex for matching an application version in javascript using pattern:

```
(0-255).(0-255)[.(0-65535).(0-65535)]
```

Here is my result:

```
^(?:(\d+)\.){1}(?:(\d+)\.){1}(?:(\d+)\.)?(\d+)?$
```

But it allows strings with dot in the end (like '111.222.333.') and doesn't limit number of digits.
Any help?

**Update**

This pattern is better:

```
(0-255).(0-255)[.(0-65535)][.(0-65535)]
```

The result is:

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.](?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:(?:[.](?:[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])){1})?(?:(?:[.](?:[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])){1})?$
```

Comment: Regex is not the best tool for what you want to accomplish.

Comment: split('.'), loop and parseInt may be easier

Comment: You could make a first pass of validation with `/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,5}\.\d{1,5})?$/` and then split the string on `.`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis OP asks for range between 0-255 and 0-65535

Comment: @Bondye I know that. That's why I said it was a *first pass* validation, then splitting on periods to validate the ranges.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for you would be to split by `.` and check each part:

```js
function isInBounds(value, min, max) {
    return !isNaN(value) && value >= min && value <= max;
}

function checkVersion(version) {
    var parts = version.split(".");
    switch (parts.length) {
    case 4:
    case 3:
        for (var i = 2; i < parts.length; i++) {
            if (!isInBounds(parseInt(parts[i], 10), 0, 65535)) {
                return false;                
            }
        }
        // fallthrough
    case 2:
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (!isInBounds(parseInt(parts[i], 10), 0, 255)) {
                return false;                
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(checkVersion("foo"));                 // false
console.log(checkVersion("foo.bar"));             // false
console.log(checkVersion("foo.bar.foo"));         // false
console.log(checkVersion("foo.bar.foo.bar"));     // false
console.log(checkVersion("256"));                 // false
console.log(checkVersion("256.256"));             // false
console.log(checkVersion("256.256.65536"));       // false
console.log(checkVersion("256.256.65536.65536")); // false
console.log(checkVersion("42"));                  // false
console.log(checkVersion("42.42"));               // true
console.log(checkVersion("42.42.42"));            // true
console.log(checkVersion("42.42.42.42"));         // true
```

See on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8053Lwb/)

---

Regex is probably not the way to go, since it does not handle ranges very good. Just for the challenge, here is the one you would need ([RegexForRange](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range) helped a lot `;)`):

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.](?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:(?:[.](?:[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])){1,2})?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NwZTHgSeKN08Gw_6)

Comment: never heard of debuggex... that's a pretty nifty visualization!

Comment: Many thanks! It's work for me: `^(?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.](?:[0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:(?:[.](?:[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])){1})?(?:(?:[.](?:[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])){1})?$`